# Is the $S$-Matrix analytic in Planck constant?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, s-matrix-theory, analyticity, non-perturbative

Taking the scattering amplitude as a function of $\hbar$, is such function necessarily analytic in this variable.

Suppose I'm concerned with Relativistic Quantum Field Theory.

In QED, the tree level correction to the scattering amplitude which is the on-shell limit of the fermionic 4-point Green function, is proportional to $\hbar^{-1}$.

Is this a counter example of non-analyticity of the $S$-Matrix in terms of the Planck constant?

---

EDIT: For those that in my opinion are correctly objecting to the fact that analyticity/functoriality in a dimensionful quantity in Physics is not meaningful.

What if I take a value of $\hbar$ and make a relative perturbations around this arbitrarily chosen $\hbar$? I mean an expansion in terms of $δ \hbar /\hbar$?

I want to know how does the $S$-matrix behave if one applies some relative fluctuations around $\hbar$?

Ιn fact the question is about the scaling of the S-Matrix with $ℏ$.

Since:

$δℏ/ℏ=δ\log(ℏ/ℏ_0)$

**AS IF** $ℏ$
depends on energy scale and it can scale logarithmically in a hypothetical scenario.

Comment: That cannot be relevant to anything because $\hslash$ is a unit-ful quantity, and from dimensional analysis, it can be shown that nothing in physics can depend strongly on their numerical value.

Comment: What if I take a value of $h$ and make relative perturbations around this arbitrarily chosen h? I mean an expansion in terms of $δh/h$? I want to know how does the S matrix behave if one applies some relative fluctuations around $h$? @naturallyInconsistent

Comment: I doubt it. There are arguments going back to Dyson about QED's S-matrix being non-analytic when the dimensionless number $\alpha$ is zero. And all $\hbar$ dependence of this S-matrix is contained in $\alpha$.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean, perhaps by writing the full expression you're referring to to two orders in $\hbar^{-1}$? Something with units cannot be an expansion parameter, because it cannot be large or small unless compared to something else, so you must mean something like powers of [something unit energy][something of unit 1/time]/$\hbar$. Usually QFT is done in natural units where $\hbar$ is defined to be 1, which is a big problem for this question. I vaguely remember some kind of limit of small $\hbar$ argument in QFT but I don't remember how it circumvents these issues.

Comment: This is a valid question in my opinion. There are attempts to perturbatively quantize classical theories in $\hbar$ as the quantization parameter [Perturbative Algebraic Field Theory, and Deformation
Quantization pdf](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0101079)

Comment: @ConnorBehan That's somewhat better than nothing, but is the same mistake made by Witten in interpreting large N limit as the classical limit. No. It's not a good approach to me, because I think interactions and quantumness are not ab initio linked or tauntamount. Unless one uses some more convincing reasoning, that quantumness and interactiveness are not separable! But thanks.

Comment: @ConnorBehan in fact the question is about the scaling of the S-Matrix with ${\hbar}$. $δ{\hbar}/{\hbar}=δ\log({\hbar}/{\hbar}_0) $ Maybe $\hbar$ depends on energy scale and it can scale logarithmically in a hypothetical scenario.

Comment: Please look up what natural units are.

Comment: @ConnorBehan How do you know the differences in scaling of $\hbar$, $G$ and $c$ do not cancel each other out such that Planck units remain the same. If that was your point.

Comment: @Cream My problem with this method is that how $\hbar$ going to zero is a valid interpretation of classical limit. Since physically speaking $\hbar$ is fixed in the universe. I mean what is the physical meaning of such a limit?

Comment: @AXensen I elaborated on the question and edited more.

Comment: instanton corrections are $e^{-S/\hbar}$.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform It's a very subtle point you made. Since it shows that even if you consider $exp(-S/\hbar)/\hbar$ in the $\hbar$ going to zero, the result is 0. Meaning there's no classical counterpart to instantons. Which is valid as they necessarily represent an essentially quantum effect: tunneling!

Comment: The limit $\hbar \to 0$ should be interpreted as a relative limit (as $\hbar$ has units). I.e. $\hbar$ becomes small compared to the energies considered in the system. High energies imply large numbers of particles and interactions, so this can then be seen as a classical limit.

Comment: @Cream I guess you mean $\hbar$ in comparison to the action $S$. But that's not the purpose of question.

Comment: @Cream instead you can think of the variation of the S-Matrix on the relative variation of the Planck constant: $δ\hbar/\hbar$